# Subversion - Merge skipping duplicate file name and not restoring

Tags: svn, merge, branch

Apologies if this is answered, but I waded through a bunch of articles before I decided to post this.

So I have a branch and the main trunk and I was experimenting with Merging.

/trunk/Blah
/branch/Blah/FeatureA

So I create a file "test.txt" in the branch and commited it.
I then accidentally created a file "test.txt" in the trunk

Later I attempt to merge the feature A branch to the main trunk.

It gives me the error

```
Skipped 'Test.txt'
Summary of conflicts:
  Skipped paths: 1
```

When merging.

So I realize it's because the main trunk had a non-sensical copy of the file. I delete the file from the trunk and re-run the merge command and it gives me zero output.

If I run the merge with the --dry-run, it too returns no output

If I run the diff command with the same arguments it shows the file Test.txt and that it intends to add.

So I ran off and did the test again but this time with "test2.txt". I made sure that the trunk didn't have a file named "test2.txt". I ran the merge and it ran perfectly.

So my question is, when I do accidentally have a file in the trunk with the same name that causes a conflict.

How do I get subversion to

1. Raise a conflict and ask me if it wants to replace or edit the conflict
2. Allow me to rename/delete the file so that I can simply re-run the merge and it works

Thanks!

** EDIT - With Answer **

I had a second set of eyes, apparently I neglected to add the --ignore-ancestry flag on my merge command. Once I added that, everything worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a second set of eyes, apparently I neglected to add the --ignore-ancestry flag on my merge command. Once I added that, everything worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

This kind of conflict is a **tree conflict**.
The only way to resolve the conflict is to choose a file from either trunk or branch.
There is not helper to rename during merge, you must manually solve this conflict.